# Swiftt Badge Notifications Depreciated after iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-push-notifications

So here's the story. I ended up inheriting an iphone app that im trying to help support. I'm more of a python developer than with swift but im learning as I go. I fixed a few other issues with this app but i'm stuck on the badge notifications. Apparently "UIUserNotificationType" deprecated after iOS 10. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or to any good documentation?

I need to update the below method:

```
 func initialize(application:UIApplication){

                 let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
                 let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
                 application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
                 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

I get the 3 following issues:

'UIUserNotificationType' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions'

'UIUserNotificationSettings' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings'

'registerUserNotificationSettings' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:] and -[UNUserNotificationCenter setNotificationCategories:]
I found the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions

How would I be able to put this into the UIUserNotificationType array? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How would I be able to put this into the UIUserNotificationType array?

You wouldn't, because the entire `UIUserNotificationSettings` enumeration has been deprecated. From the `UIUserNOtificationSettings` documentation:

> **Important:** UIUserNotificationSettings is deprecated in iOS 10. Use UNNotificationSettings instead. A UIUserNotificationSettings object encapsulates the types of notifications that can be displayed to the user by your app.

Also, per your error messages, `registerUserNotificationSettings()` is also deprecated. The docs for `registerForRemoteNotifications()` explain that you'll need to call the `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s `requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)` method if you want to display badges etc.